# Charts js. How to pass datasets use a select dropdown by angular instead jquery

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

I have a code for building charts with jQuery. I add new datasets in charts from dropdown list but how can I do it using AngularJS?

**html**

```
<select id="test">
    <option isabled selected value="">Choose options</option>
    <option value="kpi_2">Kpi 2</option>
    <option value="kpi_3">Kpi 3</option>
</select>
```

**js**

```
var dataFee = {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [{
                label: " ",
                data: [18, 16, 125, 65, 100, 71, 12],
                ....
            }],

        };

        var ctx = $("#myChartLine").get(0).getContext("2d");
        var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: "line",
            data: dataFee,
        });

    $('#test').change(function(){
      const val = $(this).val();

        switch (val){
            case 'kpi_2':

            var secondData = {
                label: " ",
                data: [1, 12, 115, 55, 90, 80, 22],
                .....
            };

                dataFee.datasets.push(secondData);
                myLineChart.update();

            break;
            ...
        }

    });
```

All code and example here https://plnkr.co/edit/NR7GKcyqdjJKBfWB5fTG?p=preview

Comment: Which version of angular you want to target?

Comment: I use an angular 1.5

Answer (score 0):

The Chart JS library is built for use with `jQuery` - I'd recommend against mixing in AngularJS.

If you want to use Chart JS charts with AngularJS, there is a library built just for that - `angular-chart.js`. I've used it often and it's a nice, robust little library.

http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/